# OCaml pattern match record and fields in one statement

Tags: ocaml

I want to have a match statement give me access to a record *and* some of its fields like so:

```
| Some n {left = Some l; right = Some r} -> dostuff...
```

So here, I can refer to the record (`n`) and it's fields left `l` and right `r`. Is this possible?

e.g. I want something like this

```
let rec remove_node root v =
  match root with
    | None   -> root
    | Some n when v > n.value -> do_a...
    | Some n when v < n.value -> do_b...
    | Some n when {left = Some l; right = Some r} -> do_c...
    | Some {right = Some r} -> do_d...
    | Some {left} -> do_e...
```

But I currently am writing this:

```
let rec remove_node root v =
  match root with
    | None   -> root
    | Some n ->
      (match n with
      | _ when v > n.value  -> do_a...
      | _ when v < n.value  -> do_b...
      | {left = Some l; right = Some r} -> do_c...
      | {right = Some r}    -> do_d...
      | {left}              -> do_e...
      )
```

Which is not so bad, but I wanted to avoid the nested match, if possible.

Comment: You should be able to use `as`: `Some ({left = Some l; right = Some r} as n)`

Comment: @Lee, that's pretty close to what I want, and good to know, but I would like to have n be the unboxed value (e.g. the equivalent of `| Some n -> n`, whereas in the case you give, n is Some x, rather than x. Does that make sense?

Comment: `n` should be the record `{left = Some l; right = Some r}` - is that not what you want? Sorry, I don't really know OCaml so I can't try it out myself right now.

Comment: It appears to be `Some {left; right}` rather than `{left;right}`. Not sure how to unbox it from the optional. Thanks, for trying, though!

Comment: @Lee's suggestion looks like exactly what you want. He uses `as` to make `n`   refer to the contained node value. It doesn't refer to `Some node`. Look at his parentheses, they are correct.

Comment: (Just wanted to add that if Lee is female I apologize for using "he" and "his". :-)

Comment: Yeah. Er... @Lee, do you want to answer, so I can accept your answer? If not, I'll answer.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Thanks for pointing out the parens. I'd missed those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lee pointed out in the comments above, the solution is to use `as` in parenthesis like so:

```
let rec remove_node root v =
  match root with
    | Some ({left = Some l; right = Some r} as n) -> dostuff...
```

(@Lee, if you want to answer, so I can give you credit, I'll remove this one and vote for your answer instead.)